# How to make pycharm virtual environment variables persist in windows

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, virtualenv

I am using pycharm on windows with a virtual environment made using the python `virtualenv` package. My process to create it and install dependencies is as follows.

```sh
virtualenv venv && source venv/Scripts/activate
```

On pycharm I use this same venv to run my code. My set up process is to connect it was to choose "Existing Enviornment" then navigate to `venv/Scripts/python.exe`.

While I get access to all the packages from my requirements.txt and installing new packages via pip will persist, my environment variables do not. In a PyCharm terminal when I run `export FOO=bar` then `echo $FOO` in a new terminal FOO no longer exists. However in git bash after I activate the venv I can run `export FOO=bar` and then `echo $FOO` will always print `bar` even after I deactivate and reactivate the environment.

Basically, it seems like PyCharm only pulls the python install from the virtual environment and won't use or persist any of the environment variables in it. How do I set up PyCharm so it will be able to read and write environment variables to its interpreter's virtual environment?

Comment: Usually one creates a script which set environment and then call the main program. Or just set them in your shell. Note: environment variables should not be something hardcoded, but something users want to change from default behaviour. Pycharm: you can set environment variable when you call a script

Comment: That's what I'm doing. The issue is that PyCharm isn't able to see the environment variables I previously set.